# Reverse list of lists using foldr Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, fold

I'm trying to reverse list of lists in Haskell by using foldr. There is an example of what I want to do:

```
> reverse'' [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
[[5,4,3],[3,2,1]]
```

And my code (it is not working):

```
reverse'':: [[a]]->[[a]]
reverse'' x = foldr (\n acum -> acum:(foldr(\m acum1 -> acum1++[m])) [] n) [[]] x
```

My IDE reports me an error at the start of the second foldr.

Comment: But this is not a folding job. Why don't you just do like `reverse . map reverse $ [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]`

Comment: I'm a novice in Haskell programming. There is a way to use recursion to solve my problem instead of your solution?

Comment: It's a fine exercise if you want to learn Haskell, and how recursion works, but then if that's your motivation, you shouldn't be using `foldr`, which abstracts the recursion away.

Comment: Try to first write a recursive version of `reverse`, and, likewise, a recursive version of `map`. If you can do that, you should be able to compose them as @Redu suggests.

Comment: First, write reverse in terms of foldr, then write map, then combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To analyse your current solution, I've broken down your one-liner into some helper functions, with their type deduced based on their composition:

```
reverse'':: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reverse'' x = foldr f [[]] x
    where
        f :: [a] -> a -> [a]
        f n acum = acum : reverse n

        reverse :: [a] -> [a]
        reverse n = foldr append [] n

        append :: a -> [a] -> [a]
        append m acum = acum ++ [m]
```

When I try to compile the above, ghc complains with the following error for the type signature of `reverse''`:

```
Expected type: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
  Actual type: [[a]] ->  [a]  -> [[a]]
```

I did some digging, and in order for `reverse''` to have the type `[[a]] -> [[a]]`, the function `f` needs to have the type `[a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`. However the current `f` has type `[a] -> a -> [a]`, or in this case `[[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]`.

The following has the correct type, but inserts an extra `[]` value into the start of the array, due to the starting value of the accumulator:

```
reverse'':: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reverse'' x = foldr f [[]] x
    where
        f :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
        f n acum = acum ++ [reverse n]

        reverse :: [a] -> [a]
        reverse n = foldr append [] n

        append :: a -> [a] -> [a]
        append m acum = acum ++ [m]
```

### The final solution

By changing the initial accumulator value to the empty list `[]`, as opposed to a list of an empty list `[[]]`, we end up at a working solution:

```
reverse'':: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reverse'' x = foldr f [] x
    where
        f :: a -> [a] -> [a]
        f n acum = acum ++ [reverse n]

        reverse :: [a] -> [a]
        reverse n = foldr append [] n

        append :: a -> [a] -> [a]
        append m acum = acum ++ [m]
```

### As a single line

If you really want this as a one-liner, here it is:

```
reverse'' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reverse'' = foldr (\n acum -> acum ++ [foldr (\m acum1 -> acum1 ++ [m]) [] n]) []
```

With working:

```
append m acum = acum ++ [m]
append = \m acum1 -> acum1 ++ [m]

reverse n = foldr append [] n
reverse = \n -> foldr append [] n
reverse = foldr append []
reverse = foldr (\m acum1 -> acum1 ++ [m]) []

f n acum = acum ++ [reverse n]
f = \n acum -> acum ++ [reverse n]
f = \n acum -> acum ++ [foldr (\m acum1 -> acum1 ++ [m]) [] n]

reverse'':: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reverse'' x = foldr f [] x
reverse'' x = foldr (\n acum -> acum ++ [foldr (\m acum1 -> acum1 ++ [m]) [] n]) [] x
reverse'' = foldr (\n acum -> acum ++ [foldr (\m acum1 -> acum1 ++ [m]) [] n]) []
```

### Appendix: An explicitly recursive solution

Here is an explicitly recursive solution (i.e. not using a `fold`), with definitons of `map` and `reverse` provided.

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
reverse []     = []

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
map _ [] = []

reverse'' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reverse'' ls = reverse $ map reverse ls
```

Comment: Wow dude, thank you so much! I've learned how folding and recursion work in this case!

Comment: Not a dude, but I'm glad it helped